# How to increase speed of server sent events

Tags: python, flask, server-sent-events

I'm playing around with server sent events and flask. The setup is very basic. On the client:

```
...
<script>
var source = new EventSource("/stream");
source.onmessage = function(e) {
    console.log(e);
};
</script>
...
```

And on the server I have:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, Response, redirect


app = Flask(__name__)
application = app


@app.route('/stream')
def stream():
    if request.headers.get('accept') == 'text/event-stream':
        def events():
            yield "data: {}\n\n".format("test")
            time.sleep(.1)
        return Response(events(), content_type='text/event-stream')
    return redirect("/")


@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template("index.html")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Everything works, except it is really slow. Given my delay of `time.sleep(.1)` I would have expected to see roughly 10 events per second on the client. It is however only one event every ~3 seconds.

When I increase my delay to say `time.sleep(5)`, I get an event every 8 seconds and so forth. So it looks like I have a delay of ~3 seconds between server and client, which is odd given that they run on the same machine.

The browser I use for testing is chromium, I run the development server from flask. But the same happens with gunicorn.

Do I anything wrong? Is there a way to speed up SSEs?

Answer (score 0):

I found it out myself now. I'm missing the loop in the `events()` function. Changing it to

```
def events():
    while True:
        yield "data: Test\n\n"
        time.sleep(.1)
```

solved the problem.